# Getting frequent SIGABRT crashing a console using Momo

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono

I am seeing frequent SIGABRT crashes in a Mono console application that are outside of my code.

I search stack overflow and found a similar problem (3 yrs old) that was marked resolved but I am seeing very much the same thing. That question was [Intermittent SIGSEV (segfault), SIGABORT and process hangs in C# code using Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32281658/608639).

Environment:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Linux 4.4.0-137-generic
X64 Architecture
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 * Assertion: should not be reached at sgen-scan-object.h:101

 Stacktrace:
at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_mono_gc_alloc_vector (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
at (wrapper alloc) object.AllocVector (intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.BufferUtils.RentBuffer (Newtonsoft.Json.IArrayPool`1<char>,int) <0x0002c>
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.EnsureBuffer () <0x0002b>
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () <0x00017>
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent () <0x00013>
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract,bool) <0x0007b>
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader,System.Type,bool) <0x000d7>
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader,System.Type) <0x0015f>
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader,System.Type) <0x0001b>
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (string,System.Type,Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings) <0x000eb>
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult_REF> (string,Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings) <0x0002f>
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult_REF> (string) <0x00027>
at Oxygen.xfer.GetFromJSON (string) <0x0001b>
at Oxygen.MyServiceClient.Proceed () <0x00213>
at Oxygen.IndexerEngine.IndexProcess () <0x00113>
at Oxygen.IndexerEngine.<.ctor>b__7_1 () <0x0000f>
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () <0x0004f>
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () <0x00055>
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback (object) <0x00055>
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x0016e>
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x00020>
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal (System.Threading.Tasks.Task&) <0x00116>
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry (bool) <0x000ee>
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () <0x0000e>
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () <0x001d6>
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () <0x00008>
at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:
/usr/bin/cli() [0x49ff2f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7f8964be1390]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0x7f896483b428]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a) [0x7f896483d02a]
/usr/bin/cli() [0x630409]
/usr/bin/cli() [0x63069c]
/usr/bin/cli() [0x630833]
/usr/bin/cli() [0x5fb526]
/usr/bin/cli() [0x5e8f81]
/usr/bin/cli() [0x5ea974]
/usr/bin/cli() [0x5eca95]
/usr/bin/cli() [0x5dfe72]
/usr/bin/cli() [0x5ce716]
[0x402e573e]

Debug info from gdb:
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=======================================================
Aborted
```

I am unsure how to proceed.

The code GetFromJson is really simple:

```
        public static xfer GetFromJSON(string json)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        }
```

This is call between 300 and 400 times before failing.  The associated library is used in another console app that calls it millions of times without incident. The main difference between the two apps is that the one without incident performs calculations with the CPU and the one that has issues uses an NVidia GPU accessed through OpenCL.

Comment: The cited question provides relevant code but this question lacks code. No one here has a crystal ball...

Comment: Sorry - will add.  The original posting not having code and the reference to the native libraries made me think it unnecessary.

Comment: This problem appears to be deep in Mono and difficult to debug and find.  I have rebuild my code using DotNet Core 2.1 and the system operates perfectly. I think I will adopt that as my solution to the problem given my time constraints.